# what does drive mean in the "donation drive"

Tags: meaning

What does *drive* mean in the *donation drive*?
What's the difference between *donation* and *donation drive*?

Thanks!!!

Comment: **n.** "6. A strong organized effort to accomplish a purpose. See Synonyms at *campaign* "  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/drive **noun** "3 An organized effort by a number of people to achieve a purpose" http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/drive

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be migrated to ELL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *donation* is something you give.  A *donation drive* is a campaign to raise donations.

Comment: So we usually use donation drive, not donation campaign or other phrase,right?

Comment: One more question, can I say a donation drive for the poor areas? I am not sure about the preposition.

Comment: Yes, or, a donation drive for poor areas or in poor areas.

Answer (score 1):

One of the many meanings of "drive" is a "strong determination" or "organized effort
to accomplish some purpose." So, a "donation drive" is a campaign of sorts to raise funds for a charitable cause.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Since I didn't find this meaning in the on-line dictionary. Can you share the resource with me? I mean the link of the on-line dictionary or the name of the book that you have quoted from. With your info, I can help myself next time. Thanks again!

Comment: Mine is basically a slight paraphrase and borrowing of "free-dictionary.com" Cheers!